# Django REST y android (response template)

Tags: android, django, django-rest-framework

I'm doing a project that requires connecting android and django rest and everything worked fine but there is a problem when visiting the url of the view generates a template that I do not want to show.

[image: tempalte img]

I need you to return the answer for the android application and then redirect to another page or always show the blank page.

restapp/view.py

```
class postList(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
      allpost = Post.objects.all()
      serializer = postSerializer(allpost, many=True)
      return JsonResponse({"message":"get all","state":"1","control":serializer.data})
```

project/urls.py

```
from restapp import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url('post/', views.postList.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: Why do you need to visit DRF page if you are using REST APIs ?

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge I need to make the communication between android and a project already done in django (my specialty is android does not django), that's why I do not want templates in those url

Comment: If you send some HTTP request, it will return some data.Here in your case, it will return JSON data.What you have to do is, only parse the data and use in the android application. You don't have to display the page contens

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge if it is accurate but for that I need a url to direct my Http requests and the problem is working I did not know how to skip the generation of the template when someone enters that url, so ask if someone knew how to eliminate the template or how to make of the responce and redirect the page for those who enter the url can not see anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When working with django-rest-framework APIs, it will by default generate these template for debug purpose.

This is a feature of Django-Rest-Framework. 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/browsable-api/

Whenever you'll open your API URL in browser, it will by default show this templated page.

You can disable it by removing the BrowsableAPIRenderer from REST_FRAMEWORK settings.

In your settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    # 'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer', # Remove this line or comment it
)}
```

I hope this helps.